# Regarding algebric manipulation in order to find $a_0^2 - a_1^2 + a_2^2 + ... a_{2n}^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, problem-solving, factoring

In the problem below I am unsure about the validity of the manipulation in Step 3 of the solution.

**Tldr : How is $(1/x^2+1+x^2)^n =  1/x^{2n}(1 + x^2 + x^4)^n$?**
(I plugged in small numbers and it does show that the equation is valid but I do not understand how it was deduced)

The problem :

> Given $(1+x+x^2)^n$ = $a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + .... a_{2n}x^{2n}$
>   find  $a_0^2 - a_1^2 + a_2^2 + ... a_{2n}^2$

The solution is as follows :

> **Step 1** : Let $LHS = (1+x+x^2)^n * (1- 1/x + 1/x^2)^n$
>
> $i.e : = (a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + .... a_{2n}x^{2n})(a_0 - a_1/x + a_2/x^2 +...+a_{2n}/x^{2n})$
>
> This gives us the sum that has to be found on $LHS$ as the term independent of $x$.
>
> **Step 2** : Let $RHS = (1+x+x^2)^n * (1- 1/x + 1/x^2)^n$
>                        = $[(1+x+x^2)(1- 1/x + 1/x^2)]^n$
>                        = $(1/x^2 + 1 + x^2)^n$

This is where I don't understand how $1/x^{2n}$ can be factored out :

> **Step 3** : $RHS = 1/x^{2n}(1 + x^2 + x^4)^n$
>                    = $1/x^{2n}(a_0 + a_1x^2 + a_2x^4 + ... + a_{2n}^{4n})$
>
> This indicates that the term independent of $x$ on $RHS$ is $a_n$ which is thus equal to the term independent of $x$ on $LHS$, thus giving the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(\frac1{x^2}+1+x^2\right)^n=\left(\frac1{x^2}(1+x^2+x^4)\right)^n
=\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)^n(1+x^2+x^4)^n=\frac1{x^{2n}}(1+x^2+x^4)^n.$$